# Git and same changes to multiple code bases

Tags: git

We have recently split one of our code bases into 4 separate code base by forking the main code base.

However I now have code that needs to be in 3 out of the 4 code bases to fix a pre split but that was found.

My question is how can I push my changes from one code base to the other with git without manually copying over the files.

Eg:

CodeBase1
CodeBase2
CodeBase3
CodeBase4

CodeBase1 contains the commits to fix the bug and the tests for the bug now I want to replicate those changes to CodeBase2 and CodeBase3.

I would assume I could just add them as remotes to my CodeBase1 local copy and do a git push of the specific revisions, but I want to make sure this is the right approach.

Comment: what do you call a "code base"? is it the remote repository your code is hosted to?

Comment: Yes the code base is the remote.

Comment: yep this sounds like a valid aproach to me then

Comment: Awesome thanks you all were fast and very helpful thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that would be the right approach. You want to `git pull` prior to pushing though, just in case of merge conflicts

Comment: Ok thanks. I wasn't 100% sure. I'll mark as answer as soon as I can.